# MyList = new List<int>(); works, but MyList.Clear(); doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but the following code does not produce the output I expected, unless I change the line `TheList.Clear();` to `TheList = new List<int>();`

```
     List<List<int>> ListOfLists = new List<List<int>>();
     List<int> TheList = new List<int>();

     for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
     {
        TheList.Add(i);

        if (TheList.Count < 10)
           Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " adicionado");
        else
        {
           ListOfLists.Add(TheList);
           TheList.Clear(); // THIS
        }
     }

     string AllItems = "";

     for (int i = 0; i < ListOfLists.Count; i++)
     {
        foreach (int j in ListOfLists[i])
           AllItems += j.ToString() + ",";

        AllItems += "/";
     }

     Console.WriteLine(AllItems);
```

When instantiating a new list, I get

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,/11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,/21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,/"
```

as output, but when clearing it, the output is `"///"`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
ListOfLists.Add(TheList);
```

When you create an instance of `TheList`, there is one such list in memory.  When you add `TheList` to `ListOfLists`, there is still only *one* of that original list in memory.  The above line of code doesn't create copy.

So when you do this:

```
TheList.Clear();
```

You perform a clear operation on that *one* list in memory.  Any code which holds a reference to that list (such as an element in `ListOfLists`) will be able to observe that change.  That one single list has been cleared.

However, when you do this:

```
TheList = new List<int>();
```

You create a new *separate* list in memory, and simply changes the variable `TheList` to point to the new list instead of the original one.  If there was no other reference to the original list, it would be cleaned up from memory by the garbage collector.  However, there is still a reference to it.  It's an element in `ListOfLists`.  So after the above line, you now have *two* lists in memory.  Any operations you perform on this new list doesn't affect the original list.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
ListOfLists.Add(TheList);
```

actually adds a *reference* to TheList, not a copy of it. So when you do

```
TheList.Clear();
```

you are also clearing the same list being stored in ListOfLists.

I would suggest that you don't need the `Clear()`, but rather just declare TheList a new list each time:

```
 List<List<int>> ListOfLists = new List<List<int>>();
 List<int> TheList = new List<int>();

 for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
 {
    TheList.Add(i);

    if (TheList.Count < 10)
       Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " adicionado");
    else
    {
       ListOfLists.Add(TheList);
       TheList = new List<int>();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer this as best as I can. 
when you add TheList to the ListOfLists, you are adding a reference (memory location) of TheList to the ListofLists.  so, if you use clear, by the end of your loop you will have 3 empty list in ListOfLists because you have cleared TheList refernce 3 times; Each ListOfLists cell holds a reference to the same list.

In loops like these you will need to add a new list.  Adding a new list will create a separate reference for each of the lists you create. If you clear on e of these it will not clear another.